# Right-align LaTeX longtables through R's print.xtable

Tags: r, alignment, latex, longtable

Say I have the following program in R to generate a LaTeX longtable:

```
library(xtable)
tabela <- xtabs(Temp ~ Month, airquality)
xtabela <- xtable(tabela)
print.xtable(xtabela, tabular.environment = 'longtable', floating = FALSE)
```

Which yields

```
\begin{longtable}{rr}
  \hline
 & Month \\ 
  \hline
5 & 2032.00 \\ 
  6 & 2373.00 \\ 
  7 & 2601.00 \\ 
  8 & 2603.00 \\ 
  9 & 2307.00 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

However, I want this table to be completely aligned to the right. In LaTeX, I just need to use `\begin{longtable}[r]{rr}` in order to accomplish this, but how do I pass this `[r]` argument through R's `print.xtable`? Alternatively, how do I achieve the same result through other methods (I've tried `\raggedleft`, but it only works with regular `tabular` objects)?

Answer (score 1):

As a very rough method, you could do:

```
cat(paste(c("\\begin{longtable}[r]{", align(xt), "}\n"), collapse=""))
print(xtabella, only.contents=T)    
cat("\\end{longtable}\n")
```